# Visual Studio Web Deploy does not modify Connection Strings at Publish time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

I have a WebApp `ASP.Net Core 2.1` contains multiple database connection strings, which are specified into an `appsettings.json` configuration file. When developing locally, they are set to point a Local Database for debugging purposes.

At Publish Time, those connection strings were modified by the **Visual Studio Web Deploy Publisher**, in the settings panel as per screenshot below. But, for a few days,  **those connection strings are no more modified automatically by the publisher**, despite check-boxes "Use this connection string at run time" are checked.

This is super painful : the app crashes right after publishing (cannot connect to databases) and I have to go over FTP to change manually those connection strings.

#### Context of the bug

In the past days, I created a *shared* `appsetting.json` file across multiple projects. This shared setting file is referenced as a linked file on every project. On my Web App project, I changed the startup class to embed this additional configuration file into the ConfigurationRoot. Using the default Startup constructor was not embedding this additional setting file.

```
public class Startup
{           
    //public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)  //Default Startup constructor which DOES not take into account the  sharedappsettings.json configuration file
    //{
    //    Configuration = configuration;
    //}

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var contentRoot = env.ContentRootPath;

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(contentRoot)
                .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile("sharedappSettings.json");
            Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

#### Questions

- Why the publisher not modify anymore the various connection strings, despite the interface shows that it shall do it?
- How can I override this behavior, and change those connection strings at publish time, outside of the Web Deploy interface if not possible otherwise?

#### Visual Studio Web Deploy Screenshot

[image: Visual Studio Web Deploy Publisher]

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? For checking `Use this connection string at runtime`, it will chang the connectionstring in `appsettings.production.json`. Do you want to change string in `sharedappSettings.json`?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at config transforms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-2.2

This allows you to make config changes which extend beyond connection strings for all of the environments in your pipeline.

Comment: This is an option yes, but this method is not really convenient. Thanks anyway.